# Open a toolbar on click of a button in MSOffice apps

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

What i want is to create a button on the toolbar via the standard Customize … in Office apps,  that ‘enables / calls / opens another toolbar’? This is still in Access 2003.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without VBA (but as you tagged your question this way, this is probably what your are looking for).

**First, create a macro that displays your toolbar:**

```
Sub RestoreToolbars()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars("The toolbar you want to display").Enabled = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[Source on ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/toolbar-remove-restore.htm)

**Then, create a custom button that will call that macro:**

Add or delete a toolbar button  (#addicon)

Customizing your toolbars is from customize, and there are several ways of getting into customize:

- View --> Toolbars --> Customize, --or from--
- Tools --> Customize, --or from--
- right-click on toolbars area --> Customize

To **add a button to a toolbar** select one of the choices under customize, move the button to the toolbar you want to see it in.  Click on an button in customize and look in lower left corner of customize window for it's description.

**Add or delete a toolbar button**

1. Customize (Tools --> Customize)
2. Click on the Commands tab
3. To add a button, click the name of the category in the Categories
   box, and then drag the button or item from the Buttons area to the
   displayed toolbar.

To delete a button, drag it off the toolbar to delete.
It can be moved to another toolbar, instead of deleting, but dragging it to the worksheet area will delete the button.

If a button is dragged off a toolbar during customize it can only be restored from an existing toolbar or the builtin pattern toolbars. It is for this reason that you should store originals in a hidden toolbar.

Right-click on the toolbar icon to assign a description, and to
    assign a macro.

[image]

[Source - Add or delete a button](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/toolbars.htm)